# Finding the Yield

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

In the experiment of Synthesizing t-Butyl Chloride, if you were to obtain 12g of t-butyl chloride what would the yield of the reaction be?

Amount of alcohol in the experiment is 17mL (density 0.775g/mL-1)

Molecular weight of t-Butyl alcohol = 74.12g/mol 
Molecular weight of t-Butyl chloride = 92.57g/mol

I'm really confused on how to go about calculating this as the only thing I've learnt about calculating percentage yield is (experimental value/ theoretical value) x 100%.

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: This is a [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/141/7448) question. We have a policy which states that ‎you should show your thoughts and/or efforts into solving the problem. It'll make us certain that ‎we aren't doing your homework for you. Otherwise, this question may get closed.‎

Answer (score 2):

You're having all the information that you need.

> Amount of alcohol in the experiment is 17 mL (density 0.775 g/mL)

1. From volume and density, the mass can be can calculated
2. From mass and the molar mass of the alcohol, the amount of substance (in mol) is available.
3. This will define the maximal outcome of your reaction (100% yield).
4. Calculate the amount of substance for 12 g of the butyl chloride.

> […] yield is (experimental value/ theoretical value) x 100%.

Exactly :)

Comment: I ended up getting 73% for the yield :) Thank you so much for the help Klaus, I really appreciate it!